# How to make this "design combat encounter for a fighter in stealth mission" less broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[As a DM, how can I best design a combat encounter in a stealth mission for a fighter?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133079/as-a-dm-how-can-i-best-design-a-combat-encounter-in-a-stealth-mission-for-a-fig)

I've tried to restrict the question to only deals the problem from DM side, and right now I don't know what can be added to limit the scope of the question. (and honestly I'm quite confused what's too broad from it)

What can be improved for this question?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to. As I commented on the question, there are hundreds of similar questions on the site, and there is absolutely no reason for yours to have been closed. It currently sits with 4 reopen votes, and I would expect it to get the last one it needs.

The problem you're asking about is sufficiently tightly scoped, and about a specific, answerable issue you're having at the table. It also has a system tag, which only narrows its scope further.

Its worth noting that at least one of the close votes was 'primarily opinion based', which doesn't make sense either. There has been a trend on the site recently to close questions requiring good subjective answers based on experience with this flag, which is wrong.

If some members of the community think your question is too broad or primarily opinion based then its evidence of a problem with the way close votes are being applied rather than an issue with your particular question.

Comment: I was glad to see your comment under the question in re it “fitting in just fine”, and I am pleased to support this answer as well.

Comment: The only thing we have to watch out for is if those questions end up drawing bad subjective answers. But better to give the opportunity for good and have to close than prematurely close and prevent good. Related [meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8377/what-can-we-do-to-help-promote-supported-opinion-based-answers-rather-than-closi)